# How to observe changes of computed css properties in a vanilla JS ES6 custom element

Tags: javascript, css, dom, custom-element, computed-style

I am trying to build a responsive custom element in vanilla JS that can respond to changes to its computed dimensions. I have successfully been able to observe changes to explicitly defined properties/attributes. However, I am wondering if it is possible to observe changes to the computed properties of the custom element. For example:

```js
class Custom_element extends HTMLElement {
  generate_html() {
    return `
        <style>
            :host {
                display:block;
            }          
            #element_wrapper {
                border: 1px solid grey;
                max-height     : 100%;
                max-width      : 100%; 
                min-height     : 100%;
                min-width      : 100%;            
            }
        </style>
        <div id="element_wrapper">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
        `
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.root = this.attachShadow({
      'mode': 'open'
    });
    this.root.innerHTML = this.generate_html();
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['height', 'width'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldVal, newVal) {
    console.log(name, oldVal, newVal) //Is it possible to fire this when the css computed height/width properties change?
  }

}


window.customElements.define('custom-element', Custom_element);
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#container:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <custom-element>
    Slot Content
  </custom-element>
</div>
```

Is it possible to get the attributeChangedCallback() to fire when you hover over the #container element and change the computed height/width of the custom element?

Comment: A [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) could probably help in your use case, although it's still experimental and lacking browser support.

Comment: @Bergi Yep, that is what I am looking for. I got hung up on trying to figure out how to use the observedAttributes callback to get it working. Thanks!!!

Comment: `height` and `weight` are not attributes of the DOM node. And even the CSS styles didn't change, only the *computed* dimensions. If there wasn't some kind of `resize` event (unfortunately it's only on `window`), I guess polling `clientWidth`/`clientHeight` would've been your only chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bergi pointed out in the comments, [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) is exactly what I was looking for. Apparently there is a polyfill to help support some of the older browsers.